# Not getting log in graylog server and also not getting any error

Tags: node.js, graylog2

I want to use GrayLogs with NodeJS Application.
I am using below package for that
https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2

I am using below Code, but I am not getting logs in my graylogs server also I am not getting any Error in Node Console.

```
logMsg = "Some Random String";
        let logger = new graylog2.graylog({
        servers: [
            { 'host': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', port: 12201 }
        ],
        // hostname: 'server.name', // the name of this host
                                 // (optional, default: os.hostname())
        facility: 'MyAPP',     // the facility for these log messages
                                 // (optional, default: "Node.js")
        bufferSize: 1350         // max UDP packet size, should never exceed the
                                 // MTU of your system (optional, default: 1400)
    });

    logger.log("info", logMsg);
```

Can someone please help me?

Here is the screenshot for input

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the IP and port are correct?

Comment: Have you created new input in graylog? The created input port should be the same with the port you define in you app. It's better if you can include the screenshot of you graylog input.

Comment: `logger.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('Error while trying to write to graylog2:', error);
});` is also good for tracing if there's any error.

Comment: @DatTran
Here I am attaching the screenshot. 

Also I have tried with on error statement, but I am not getting any error

Comment: @DatTran

I have attached the screenshot in post

Comment: @JayGould yes I am using correct IP and Port in my code.

Answer (score 0):

GELF is UDP based, so there are no connections in the first place - only messages being passed from one port to another.

So basically it doesn't wait for the response from the Graylog server. It's more of a fire and forget.